# Как обновлять UUID каждый раз при перезагрузке страницы?

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-admin

Есть необходимость создания пути к файлу с уникальным названием в модели.
Выглядеть должно так `"/folder/" + uuid.uuid4 + ".jpg"`.

Вариант с использованием `uuid.uuid4()` работает, но до перезапуска приложения UUID остаётся одним и тем же.

Есть варианты как генерировать UUID заново?

```
class File(models.Model):
    pks = models.CharField(default="/folder/" + str(uuid.uuid4()) + ".jpg", max_length=50)
    path = models.CharField('path', max_length=100)
    origin = models.CharField('Origin', max_length=30)
```

Так же можно вместо `uuid.uuid4()` использовать `uuid.uuid4`, в обычной ситуации без конкатенации строк он помогает каждый раз генерировать уникальный UUID, но при попытке преобразовать его в строку в поле выдаёт:

```
/folder/<function uuid4 at 0x00000000036BD550>.jpg
```

Comment: В значении default вместо строки использовать функцию, которая возвращает строку

Comment: Сработало, спасибо.